# ActionView::MissingTemplate, how can I resolve?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

After sending the file, the controller executes the render nothing: true, and should show the registered image on the screen.

In a show view, to add a banner field image to a banner category, when uploading the file after refresh, has ActionView :: MissingTemplate response error and headers error 500.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIBOO.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwDAi.png

change render nothing: true, to render head :ok

banners_controller.rb

class Admin::BannersController < Admin::PositionUpdaterController
  belongs_to :banner_category, parent_class: BannerCategory

def create
    @gallery = BannerCategory.find params[:banner_category_id]

```
@image = @gallery.banners.build

@image.image = params[:file]

@image.save

render nothing: true
```

end

In a show view, to add a banner field image to a banner category, when uploading the file after refresh, has ActionView :: MissingTemplate response error and headers error 500.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to change and **render nothing: true**, *to* **render json: nil, status :: ok**